Is a small or a large population more likely to be dominated by its outliers?
Prior to 1947, American baseball was racially segregated, with the so-called Major Leagues open only to white players. Black players played in smaller leagues called the "Negro Leagues".  Teams in each league played games only against other teams in the same league.
Until this year, it was the policy of Major League Baseball that statistics from Negro League play were not incorporated into the official statistics.  For example, a Negro League player who had accumulated a large number of home runs would not have been included on the list of players with the most home runs, regardless of how their total compared with those of players in the Major Leagues.  And if a player had played in both Negro and Major leagues, only their Major League performance was counted in the official statistics.
One rationale given for this policy decision was that the Negro Leagues were much smaller than the Major Leagues. The argument was that hitting a large number of home runs in the Negro Leagues might not be as difficult as doing the same in the National League, because the pitchers in the National League would overall have been better than those in the Negro Leagues.
My question is whether this is mathematically plausible. The Major League populations of pitchers were certainly larger than those of Negro Leagues, and so might include most of the really excellent pitchers.  But by the same argument a larger league would also have included more sub-par pitchers.  In fact, the great majority of professional baseball players are below-average performers, because talent (however measured) is heavily right-skewed.  I can't guess which effect will dominate the other. (Perhaps neither.)
In this question I am only interested in the mathematics, and not in any sort of historical or policy issues.

For concreteness:

Let's suppose that baseball talent in any particular area (home run hitting or what have you)

is normally distributed in the general population
but professional baseball players are drawn from the rightmost tail of this distribution, say the people who are $4.5$ or more standard deviations above the mean.       (This is why talent distributions are right-skewed.)


Suppose that the population of baseball players has been arbitrarily (uniformly randomly) divided into a small group with fraction $f$  of all players, and a large group with $1-f$ fraction of the players.  (Historically, I think around $f\approx \frac18$ of players played in the Negro Leagues.)

My question is: Are the outliers in the small group more extreme, relative to the rest of their group, than the outliers in the large group are relative to the rest of the large group?


I imagine that probability theory has a standard definition of an "outlier" and a way to measure how extreme a particular outlier is.  Is this correct?
Perhaps the answer is as simple as comparing the expected standard deviations of the two groups?  I don't know.

Interesting question perhaps better asked at stats.stackexchange.com.

Is there any reason to think that the threshold for talent (in terms of number of standard deviations above the mean) for the Negro Leagues was the same as for the Major Leagues?  I would imagine that, since whites tended to have more opportunities for good careers in other areas than blacks at that time, a white man might have been less likely to choose a career in baseball than a black man with the same level of talent.  So even if there were the same number of positions available relative to the population, the threshhold might have been higher in the Negro Leagues.

That is a good question, one I should look into as part of a larger investigation.  But I'd like to resolve this purely mathematical question also.
